# animate scrolling in scrollbars

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there any plugin available for jquery to animate the scroll? Say I have few scrollbars in the window. I want that whenever user is scrolling the scrollbar should animate and not appear instantaneously.

To get an exact idea of what I am trying to achieve, see this:

http://demo.xceed.com/DataGrid_Silverlight/Demo_1.3/

This is in Silverlight.

See how it scrolls in fluid manner. I want to achieve the same effect but using jquery. Is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Seems it would require a remodification of the scroll function. Since there is plenty of smooth scrolling scripts, but none where the scroll actually becomes smooth like the demo you linked to. Don't even know if its possible :(

Comment: i cant view the demo as of now as 1)I dont have silverlight installed, i dont intend to install it either.
2)Im on dialup, cant instal it :P

If what you need is scrollbars in a div, this can be achieved using jqueryUI and its pretty smooth.
See user934278's answer!

Answer (score 1):

1. Use jQuery UI: http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#default.
2. Insert code into the ready handler as shown here:

   ```
   var width = $('#scrollable').width() - $('#wrapper').width();

   $('#slider')
       .slider( { max: width })
       .bind('slide', function(event, ui) {

           $('#scrollable').stop().animate(
               {
                   right: ui.value
               },
               1000
           );
       });
   ```
3. HTML:

   ```
   <div id="wrapper">
       <div id="scrollable"><!-- bla bla --></div>
       <div id="slider"></div>
   </div>
   ```
4. Don't forget to hide the scrollbar:

   ```
   #wrapper {
       text-align: left;
       width: 900px;
       height: 600px;
       margin: 0 auto;
       border: 1px solid black;
       overflow: hidden;
       position: relative;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Some thing like this might help.

```
$("html, body").animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, "slow");
```

Comment: You have completely misunderstand the question and this answer is not at all relevant to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could make your own custom "sliders" using jQuery UI, and then upon change, do what "userD" suggested. One slider would be horizontal, one vertical (of course).

Then you'd want to hide the browsers actual scroll bars for the particular div by using css ("overflow: hidden;")

Here's was @userD suggested....

> $("html, body").animate({
>               scrollTop: 0
>           }, "slow");

You would of course change that to "#myDiv" instead of "html, body".

Comment: Well, @userD removed his answer due to haters bashing him so quickly :(

Answer (score 0):

A nice light plugin jQuery .scrollTo. Found here: [Arial Fiesler Blog](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html)

sytanx is easy `$('div').scrollTo(#anchorindiv,{duration:1000});`